Is it possible that the Fourier transform $F:L^2[0,2\pi]\to l^p(\mathbb{Z})$?
Flolklore: The Fourier transform $F:L^2[0,2\pi]\to l^2(\mathbb{Z})$
defined by $F(u)(m)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-imt}u(t)\,dt$, is an isomorphism.
Is it possible a similar result for $F:L^p[0,2\pi]\to l^p(\mathbb{Z})$? (with $1<p<\infty$)
